# Styling a React Material UI Component with a .map function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

So I have an array of Material UI components (for my cut down version here I'm using two simple `Button` components).

How do I add style to these components **as I iterate through them in the map function** ?

For example how would I adjust the size of the icon to be say 64px x 64px ?

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import SaveIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Save";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
export default function App() {
  const buttons = [
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="primary"
      size="large"
      startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
    >
      Save
    </Button>,
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      color="secondary"
      size="large"
      startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
    >
      Delete
    </Button>
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {buttons.map(currButton => {
        //How do I add style to each of these components as I iterate through them ?
        return currButton;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through an array of functions that take `props` as argument and return `Button` components with whatever additional `props` you pass.

```js
export default function App() {
  const buttons = [
    props => (
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        size="large"
        startIcon={<SaveIcon />}
        {...props}
      >
        Save
      </Button>
    ),
    props => (
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        size="large"
        startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
        {...props}
      >
        Delete
      </Button>
    )
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {buttons.map(createButton => {
        const CustomButton = createButton({
          style: { backgroundColor: "red" }
        });
        return CustomButton;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This approach works fine in CodeSandbox. However I get a type error when running it up in my dev mode. (Note: I am using Flow for type checking) - I get the following error : TypeError: createButton is not a function. Any idea why ?

Comment: @SimonLong are you sure you have exactly the same thing in `CodeSandbox` as you have in your local environment? What does `console.log(typeof createButton)` show? Type checking shouldn't be affecting anything.

Comment: Definitely the same code. Even pasted yours in. console.log(typeof createButton) is giving Object

Comment: @SimonLong it makes no sense, could you show a screenshot of the code that you're trying and is giving you that `TypeError`?

Comment: Here it is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sBhvf4ZJ9SFQJ72xqsvL45vxMEdmPbrm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SimonLong can you upload it to something like https://imgur.com/ and share the link?

Comment: @SimonLong could you show the `leftButtons` array as well? It looks like `currButton` is an object of type `Button` and not a function.

Comment: My sincere apologies. I just noticed in your example that buttons is an array of functions. Sorry. #mortified

Comment: @SimonLong glad you were able to figure out